# How to save Image from one table into another via php?

Tags: php, database, image, mysqli

I have two separate tables in my database. One for raw Images and other for Labelled Images. I want it to behave like this:

1. A random Image is obtained from first database on the front end using following query:

```html
 <form
  <div class="col-4 col-12-small">
                        <input type="radio" id="radio-Fear" name="radio" value="7">
                        <label for="radio-Fear">Fear</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-4 col-12-small">
                          <input type="radio" id="radio-Sadness" name="radio" value="8">
                          <label for="radio-Sadness">Sadness</label>
                        </div>
                      </br>
                        <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button primary fit" /></li>
                           <li><a href="label_images.php" class="button">Skip</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="button">Quit</a></li>
               </ul>
</form>
```

Connection String:

```
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db1 = "raw_images";
$db2 = "labelled_images";
$conn1 = mysqli_connect('localhost',$user,$pass,$db1);
$conn2 = mysqli_connect('localhost',$user,$pass,$db2);
if(!$conn1||!$conn2)
{
die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Image Retrieval from first database:

```
   <div class="image fit">
   <?php
   //Connection with DB

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_raw_image WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM tbl_raw_image ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) t)";
   $sth = $conn1->query($sql);
   $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
   $id=$result['id'];
   $image=$result['image'];
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image ).'"/>'; ?>
       </div>
```

Image storing in second database:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$label=$_POST['radio'];
$query2="INSERT INTO tbl_labelled_image(image, label, id_in_raw_image_table) VALUES('$image','$label','$id'); ";
$rs  = mysqli_query($conn2, $query2);
}
```

Comment: "I'm obtaining onto the front end is quite random and hence it is not possible for me to use the same ID to perform a direct move within tables" can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Yes I mean to say that if I were using a sequential order or smething predictible I would have store the pre-determined value in a variable and then have used it as an ID so that same image is displayed onto front end and using that same ID I would have store it in the other database but here I'm using an ID that is randomly generated on the run-time therefore this planned approach is not possible. I'm also adding this in question itself thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Send the id returned from the select statement along with the labels added by the user back to the server.

Comment: Usually the id should be held within a hidden field in the HTML form you use to post the labels

Answer (score 0):

Your query is really to complex. If I understood your problem correctly you can try the below query to achieve the desired output required.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_raw_image 
WHERE id = ROUND((RAND() * (MAX(id)-MIN(id)))+MIN(id));

INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_raw_image_2 (id, name, BLOB) 
SELECT id, name, BLOB FROM tbl_raw_image 
WHERE id = ROUND((RAND() * (MAX(id)-MIN(id)))+MIN(id));
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: My query is based on ID selection on the basis of availabilty and returning image n that ID i.e. it searches for a random noumber whose value is within the IDs of available records and then displays the image that corresponds that ID

Comment: BTW @Rohit 007 are you sure ROUND((RAND() * (MAX(id)-MIN(id)))+MIN(id)) will give the same integer both the times?

Comment: No its an example, Ideally we can store the random value in a variable, and that variable should be used in the queries

Comment: True that we can store the random value in a variable but @Rohit 007 problem remains intact then. To retrieve minimum and maximum I must have to execute a SELECT query first and then I have to commit the required queries. If I'm unable to execute them alone, how would I manage to run a third query as well.